# Async method doesnt get invoked on app startup - Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm on Spring 3 and using a basic Kafka subscribe and poll mechanism to consume and process messages like the code snippet given below
From our consumer dashboards I can see the app isnt subscribing to the topic, looks like the method is not at all invoked, no errors too. How do I resolve this issue??

```
 @Async
 @Override
 public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent applicationContextEvent) {
       log.info("Subscribing to topic={}", topic);
       consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
       while (true) {
          try {
             ConsumerRecords<String, Order> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
             messageProcessor.processMessages(records);
             consumer.commitAsync();
          } catch (Exception e) {
             log.error("Exception when consuming the  messages from kafka ", e);
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to invoke `onApplicationEvent()` upon startup of the application, if so the correct annotation is `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` 
Although it is not very clear to me where this method is located, another option is to use `@PostConstruct` if your class is a service or component that can start listening to Kafka after the constructor of your class.

Again, it depends on your implementation. I hope this helps.